# Nothing Resizes in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableviewcell that I made a custom class for as below. I am trying to make changes to things during runtime so I tried to update the frame of one of the cell's children elements that is linked but it doesnt change the size.

```
class Event_TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var legTableHolder: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        legTableHolder.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 25, height: 25)
        legTableHolder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
}
```

The background color of the `UIView` does change to blue, but the size of it does not.

Comment: Have you read this tutorial? https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift It's a little dated, but the advice there should still be helpful.

Comment: In general, changing a table view cell subview's frame isn't enough to change it's height within a table view. The recommended way to do this is by changing auto layout constraints. This can also be done indirectly by using subviews who derive their intrinsic size from their contents (e.g. `UILabel`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autolayout, modifying the frame will have no effect.

Instead, you should modify the constraints.

In xib, go to first tab, under Interface Builder Document , uncheck use Auto Layout box.

Comment: Will this remove autolayout for all my components or just this specific uiview?

Comment: This is odd, normally I can just change the frame in my code and it works.  It's only in this specific case where I am trying to make the change in the awakeFromNib for a uitableviewcell to change it's child content.